# google.cloud.tasks_v2beta3 create_task() specify headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-tasks

google.cloud.tasks_v2beta3==2.2.0 / python3.7

Looking for some help on how to specify headers in task creation. Code so far:

```
response = get_cloud_tasks_client().create_task(
        parent=queue,
        task=types.Task(http_request=types.HttpRequest(
            url=f"https://{SERVICE_DOMAIN}" + api,
            http_method=types.HttpMethod.POST,
            headers=[types.HttpRequest.HeadersEntry(mapping={"Content-Type": "foo"})],
            body=dumps(body),
            oidc_token=types.OidcToken(service_account_email=SA_OIDC_EMAIL)
        )),
    )
```

The docs says Sequence of `HeadersEntry` for `headers` parameter, but I'm not sure how to specify my custom headers.

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 501, in __init__
    pb_type = self._meta.fields[key].pb_type
KeyError: 'Content-Type'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

....
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 507, in __init__
    "Unknown field for {}: {}".format(self.__class__.__name__, key)
ValueError: Unknown field for HeadersEntry: Content-Type
```

Comment: posted an answer is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,While Creating Google Cloud Task programmatically using python 3.7, you came across an error specifying KeyError: 'Content-Type' because of some specification issue in custom header code.

Followings is the troubleshooting approaches you can take to resolve this Custom Header error:
Same task can be created by including dictionary and types both by replacing your code with the following code:

```
task_with_mix = tasks_v2.Task(

    http_request=tasks_v2.HttpRequest(
        headers={"Content-type": "application/json"},
        http_method=tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
        url=f"https://{SERVICE_DOMAIN}" + api,
        body=body,
        oidc_token={"service_account_email": SA_OIDC_EMAIL},
    )
)
```

Can create request dict:

```
request = {"parent": parent, "task": task}
client.create_task(request)
```

For more information related to Creation of Cloud tasks you can refer to this documentation on [Creating HTTP Target tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks).